# Add custom attributes to Vuetify tags

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, schema.org, vuetify.js, microdata

How I can add custom attributes to [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com) tags. I want add some [Schema.org](https://schema.org/TechArticle) attributes to my site.

I have template like this:

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v-layout row wrap >
            <v-flex xs12>
                <h1 class="content-title display-1">{{ post.title }}</h1>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex xs12>
                <div class="content-body" v-html="getMarkdown(post.text)"></div>
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
    </v-container>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

Vuetify will usually “pass on” your custom attributes, unless they collide with something that's in their API. In other words, this *will* work (it's not clear from your question what you tried that didn't):

```
<v-btn itemprop="thing" />
```

However, a more generic and stable solution would probably be to add that markup to a wrapping element, or to create your own component that wraps the Vuetify component. Or use `<meta>` tags (yes, they are allowed in the body).